# Swift Changing NSTextField text

Tags: swift, text

I am having this weird issue with my program, I am using a NSTextField but whenever I select the text field, initially it will work fine and it will select all of it for me to type but afterwards, I will have to press on the text field three times - which selects all text within the text field - and then I can overwrite what was initially there.

Does anyone have a clue why this is?

```
@IBAction func hostText(sender: AnyObject) {
        hostNameString = hostIP.stringValue
    }
```

Comment: I neither have any idea what this is, nor what you mean. *"initially it will work fine and it will select all of it for me to type"* - what is *it*? what gets *select*ed?

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: @mat there isn't much code revolving around the NSTextField but I posted what the function does after the user enters something into the text field and hits enter. I am not sure why but the text field itself is preventing me from easily modifying the text after the first time.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is `hostIP`? I believe you have a `textField` and you want to set `hostNameString` with the text in that textField. is that correct? Do you have any button?

Comment: Essentially what is happening is, I have a textfield where the user can enter a host IP address to connect to. I have it set up so that the user simply hits the `enter` button for so that the `hostNameString` is set to the textfield value. But the issue here is that I can only do this once, if I try to edit/modify the textfield, it will highlight the textfield without letting me changing the contents

Comment: so `hostText` is the action connected to the button?

Comment: @QQPrinti if I understood well `hostText` is the action connected to your button. You have to use `text` instead of `stringValue` to assign that text to your string.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well `hostText` is the action connected to your button. You have to use `text` instead of `stringValue` to assign that text to your string. I tested it and it works.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var hostIP: UITextField!
    var hostNameString:String?


    @IBAction func hostText(sender: AnyObject) {

     hostNameString = hostIP.text

     print(hostNameString)

}
```

Comment: I am actually coding for OS X so I am using `NSTextField`, retrieving the string isn't much of an issue. The issue lies on the fact that once I hit enter into the text field, it appears to lock this string into place.